# Display tooltip on press in react hooks and hide after few seconds

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks

I would like to display `phonenumber` as `tooltip`during onPress(),the below code display the data always. How to make dispay during onPress and hide in 5 seconds.

```
    const [phoneTooltip, setPhoneTooltip] = useState({
        show: false,
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        orientLeft: false
      });

  const displayPhoneToolTip = event => {
    if (!phoneTooltip) {
    setPhoneTooltip(true) // display tooltip
     }
   }

 <span className="phoneNumber_home">
    <img src="/images/phone_image.png" name="phoneNumberhomeicon" onPress={displayPhoneToolTip}/>
    <div key={phonenumber}>{phonenumber}</div>
 </span>
```

Comment: Where is `tooptip`? can you create codesandbox sample with issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your state is an object so you need to make checks using `phoneTooltip.show` and not just `phoneTooltip`.
- Also make use of setTimeout to remove tooltip after your desired time

[A quick demo is here using your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-small-tooltip-issue-fix-tj7mc?file=/src/App.js)

**Code snippet**

```js
const displayPhoneToolTip = (event) => {
  if (!phoneTooltip.show) {
    setPhoneTooltip((prev) => ({ ...prev, show: true })); // show tooltip
    setTimeout(() => {
      setPhoneTooltip((prev) => ({ ...prev, show: false })); // remove/hide tooltip
    }, 5000);
  }
};
```

Comment: I have tried that still the number always displays and no tool tip action performed

Comment: @soccerway, no one can't guess why it doesn't work on **your** project, you have a practical demo in this answer which do work.

Comment: My bad, now it working fine in my case..awesome @gdh, upvoted and accepted.

Comment: Awesome response mate. Can I clarify one thing again mate ?  what will be change we need to do if there are list of `div`s iterated in a page with id. Now when i click one of div's tool tip, all of the tool tip of other div's are also displaying...

Comment: I have changed the code to `const displayPhoneToolTip = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setPhoneTooltip(searchResults.id); // show tooltip
    setTimeout(() => {
      setPhoneTooltip(false); // remove/hide tooltip
    }, 3000);
  };`

Comment: {phoneTooltip === searchResults.id && (
                    <div className="tooltip_PhoneNumber_home" key={phonenumber}>{phonenumber}</div>
                    )}

Comment: I need to display the tool tip only for the div that I have clicked ..